# A phone app on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

As I understand it is impossible to write a Phone app on iPhone like the built-in one attached to the OS. It's because of the API exposed Apple does not allow us to do that. Someone please confirm. Many thanks!

I asked that because I have a friend who has a problem with his voice after taking a surgery due to the throat cancer. His voice is so weak that listeners could not  catch him. It drives me to an app where somehow it could increase his voice before transmitting.

Highly appreciate if you could give me some hints to come up with better ideas like with Android.

Answer (score 1):

As you say it is not possible to write a replacement phone app in iOS. Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to change the core functionality of the device.

There might be an option in the Accessibility APIs. Apple is generally pretty good about providing hooks that let you create adaptive enhancements for the handicapped.

Another option would be a hardware device that plugs into the earphone jack. That jack uses a standard connector. There may be headsets that offer a very sensitive microphone with adjustable volume boost.

Comment: Thanks Duncan! I will look at the accessibility API but I need a confirmation on that we could not write a phone app because Apple does not expose API for doing that. I did think about the hardware device and it would be an alternative or the best choice my friend would have to go with :-).